# PHP7-dev build for OSX does not contain pecl

Tags: php, macos, mongodb

I installed php7-dev version from http://php-osx.liip.ch/ and the install process happens without a problem.

Unfortunately when I try to install mongo (or any for that matter) pecl extension I can't with the message : Could not open input file: /usr/local/php5/lib/php/peclcmd.php

When I install 5.6.8 from the same source I have no problem.

I've compared both directories and indeed it is missing

```
ls -lsa /usr/local/php5-7.0.0-dev-20150417-194402/lib/php/
total 4
0 drwxr-xr-x   4 root wheel  136 Apr 22 21:18 .
0 drwxr-xr-x 197 root wheel 6698 Apr 22 21:18 ..
4 lrwxr-xr-x   1 root wheel   25 Apr 22 21:18 build -> /usr/local/php5/lib/build
0 drwxr-xr-x   3 root wheel  102 Apr 22 21:18 extensions
```

vs

```
ls -lsa /usr/local/php5-5.6.8-20150417-141945/lib/php/peclcmd.php 
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root wheel 1022 Apr 17 08:19 /usr/local/php5-5.6.8-20150417-141945/lib/php/peclcmd.php
```

Answer (score 0):

The PECL command is dependant on PEAR, since PEAR is not coming to PHP7, for the moment you must install extensions manually.

There is talk of a new package manager for extensions, though no concrete plans that I am aware of.

When this changes, and it might, I will update this answer.